# WordPress Supersized alt tags

Tags: wordpress, integration, alt, supersized, media-library

I am using **Supersized** plugin for **WordPress** (built-in "**Direction**" theme found on ThemeForest), but after many attempts I can't figure how to make it to put used alt and tile tags from **WordPress Media Library** images.
Maybe you could provide me some help? It is very relevant for slider images to be indexed by search engine crawlers, and without alt tags taken from WP Media Library it is impossible.
Darius.

The Site, I am referring to is: http://opal-escence.com/ - and images missing alt tags, are background slider images.